# How to reverse each letter of a word in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s="I love you"
```

How can I get `"I evol uoy"`?

I tried...

```
words=s.split()

for x in words:
    c=list(x)
    c.reverse()
    " ".join(c)
```

And I get...

```
'I'
'evol'
'uoy'
```

I again tried...

```
words=s.split()
s1=[]

for x in words:
   c=list(x)
   c.reverse()
   for y in c:
       s1.append(y)
```

Now `s1` is:

```
['I', 'e', 'v', 'o', 'l', 'u', 'o', 'y']
```

But there is no space between words.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the words then loop over and [reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931095/2549021) each word and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them.

```
>>> s = "I love you"
>>> " ".join(word[::-1] for word in s.split())
'I evol uoy'
```

Comment: `_` is a poor choice for a variable name

Comment: I think it is not if you have to ignore it.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I was under the impression that I have to somehow return it in the list or generator. But it seems that's not the case. I do use it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to fix your first solution:

```
s = "I love you"

words = s.split()

def reverse_word(x):
    c = list(x)
    c.reverse()
    return "".join(c)

result = " ".join(reverse_word(w) for w in words)

print(result)
```

The important things to fix are that:

1. Simply calling `" ".join(c)` without making use of it somewhere doesn't help. `c` is a copy of `x`, and reversing it doesn't change `x`.
2. `" ".join(c)` is wrong anyway because you don't want a space between letters, so it's now `"".join(c)`. The spaces are added to the actual reversed sentence.

And the second one:

```
s1 = []

for x in words:
    new_word = []
    c = list(x)
    c.reverse()
    for y in c:
        new_word.append(y)
    s1.append("".join(new_word))

result = " ".join(s1)
```

The important difference here is that you need a list for each word (consisting of letters) as well as for the whole sentence (consisting of words), since as you saw a single list for both doesn't work. I've kept it similar to your code but the `new_word` is actually redundant since it's just an exact copy of `c`. So it could be simplified as follows:

```
s1 = []

for x in words:
    c = list(x)
    c.reverse()
    s1.append("".join(c))

result = " ".join(s1)
```

This is an extremely common pattern: create an empty list, append some element to it in each iteration of a for loop, and then keep the final result. It's so common that Python has a special syntax for it called list comprehensions:

```
def reverse_word(x):
    c = list(x)
    c.reverse()
    return "".join(c)

s1 = [reverse_word(word) for word in words]
```

This is the more elegant, Pythonic way. In fact you'll notice now that the first bit of code above is almost exactly this, except that I immediately used `s1` without even naming it, and there are no square brackets because now it's a generator comprehension and a nice little feature of Python's syntax means that just the parentheses are valid since `join` only takes a single argument. But now we're getting deep, don't worry too much.

Finally `reverse_word(word)` can simply be replaced by `word[s::-1]` using Python's slice notation, and everything can be done in one step, and that's the solution given by AKS.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into words, reverse each word then join them.

```
' '.join(i[::-1] for i in s.split())
```